# Serverless AWS Certificate Manager : couldn't find certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-certificate-manager

Already followed steps to create AWS Certificate Manager

1. Verified correct domain name is used
2. DNS verified
3. Created route 53 record

Created it in us-west-2 (same region as rest of the Application)

Detailed Stack Trace:

```
Serverless: [AWS apigateway 404 0.247s 0 retries] getDomainName({ domainName: '<>' })
Serverless Domain Manager: NotFoundException: Invalid domain name identifier specified
Serverless: [AWS acm 200 0.412s 0 retries] listCertificates({
  CertificateStatuses: [ 'PENDING_VALIDATION', 'ISSUED', 'INACTIVE', [length]: 3 ]
})

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: Error: Could not find the certificate <>.
      at ServerlessCustomDomain.<anonymous> (/Users/bapac/chai_mxnet_infra/mxnet-bot/MXNetCIBot/mxnet_ci_bot_lambda/node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/index.js:280:23)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (/Users/bapac/chai_mxnet_infra/mxnet-bot/MXNetCIBot/mxnet_ci_bot_lambda/node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/index.js:4:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.invoke (/snapshot/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:490:22)
      at /snapshot/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:525:24
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.run (/snapshot/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:525:8)
      at /snapshot/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:133:33
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:130:23)
  From previous event:
      at Serverless.run (/snapshot/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:120:74)
      at /snapshot/serverless/bin/serverless.js:82:30
      at /snapshot/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:144:16
      at /snapshot/serverless/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:65:14
      at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:146:23)
  From previous event:
      at /snapshot/serverless/bin/serverless.js:82:8
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:130:23)
  From previous event:
      at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/serverless/bin/serverless.js:71:4)
      at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1324:22)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:813:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:14)
      at Function.Module.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1379:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              12.13.1
     Framework Version:         1.66.0 (standalone)
     Plugin Version:            3.4.1
     SDK Version:               2.3.0
     Components Version:        2.22.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It so happens that despite rest of the System being on us-west-2b region (Oregon). AWS Certificate Manager needs to be created in us-east-1a

Atleast that's what worked for me.